# Get Version from Non Executing Executable File

Tags: c#

I know how to get the version of an executing application or dll.  However I need to find the properties of a non executing application.

I have a small program to set a file association for my main application.  There is no point in users of old versions running this since the application does not accept arguments on start up.  So when the file associator starts it first checks to see if it can find the main app.  If it can then I want to check the properties without executing it.  If the version is earlier than one that can accept arguments then I want to tell my user to update rather than proceed to set the association.

I have looked at System.IO.FileInfo but that does not seem to include any Version information.

Thanks

Comment: Files don't have version information in Windows.

Comment: @hogan Apparently .exe and .dll files store this info somewhere, because you can view it by right-clicking, selecting Properties and then Details. It's there.

Comment: PE files can have version information on Windows. It's inside a resource embedded in the PE file.

Comment: @Hogan by "non executing" he means `exe` file on disk, that is not currently executing as a process.

Comment: @dandan78 @Shadow - I miss-read the question.  Of course version information is included in the metadata for .dll and .net exes.  Of course there is no guarantee this information will exist for an executable (E.g. a .com).  This is quite different than an operating system that does provide version information (e.g. VMS).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()`:

```
FileVersionInfo vi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("myfile.dll");
```

string showVersion = vi.FileVersion;

//showVersion is the actual version No.

This returns file/document metadata and can be used for **unmanaged DLLs or even word documents as well**.

You can also use Assembly:

```
Version v = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("myfile.dll").GetName().Version;
```

This will contain .**NET version information**.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and SO simple!